Ribbis (Interest) - Currency on plane (Seah B'Seah)
The Shulchan Aruch rules in YD 162 that it is forbidden to lend an item (which price fluctuates often (Yatza HaSha'ar) or that the lender doesn't have (Yesh Lo) and in return the item will be return as the price may go up.
The consensus of opinion among the Poskim is that foreign currency that is not readily usable in the country where the loan is taking place is considered as goods rather than currency and therefore the above would apply.
My question is if one would borrow money on a plane - midair how would we view this. For example if one was flying from the UK to Israel and borrowed GBP when one was over Italy, would we say that since he is flying from the UK it is not considered foreign currency or would we view the destination (Israel) as the determining currency or the country (Italy) where the loan is happening as the determining currency?

Or do you view the plane as its own location? They will happily take pounds sterling for in-flight duty-free the entire flight from Heathrow to Ben Gurion. Anyone on the plane can buy stuff in sterling right then and there -- should be mutar. Shekels, I don't know.
